# comparing two dimensional array js

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I am coding something in JS and I have to test code  - I have to check if elements in 2 arrays are the same.
So I've got an array: `boreholes = [[66000, 457000],[1111,2222]....];` and I want to check if this array contain element for eg. [66000,457000] so I did:
`boreholes.indexOf([66000,457000])` but it returns -1, so I iterate trough array by:

```
for (var i = 0; i< boreholes.length; i++){
 if (boreholes[i] == [66000, 457000]){
  console.log('ok');
  break;
 }
};
```

but still I've got nothing. Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing distinct objects. When comparing objects, the comparison only evaluates to `true` when the 2 objects being compared are *the* same object. I.E

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = a;
a === b //true
b = [1,2,3];
a === b //false, b is not the same object
```

To compare arrays like this, you need to compare all of their elements separately:

```
for (var i = 0; i < boreholes.length; i++) {
    if (boreholes[i][0] == 66000 && boreholes[i][1] == 457000) {
        console.log('ok');
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure this is only way to do this? can you explain me why i have to do this this way?

Comment: @Krystian If you could do this your way, the language would just implicitly do the same individual comparisons I am doing explicitly. It's just how it works with non-scalar values.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot compare arrays like `array1 == array2` in javascript like you're trying to do here.

Here is a kludge method to compare two arrays:

```
function isEqual(array1, array2){
  return (array1.join('-') == array2.join('-'));
}
```

You can now use this method in your code like:

```
for (var i = 0; i< boreholes.length; i++){
 if (isEqual(boreholes[i], [66000, 457000]){
  console.log('ok');
  break;
 }
};
```

Comment: beware, the condition will be true if the array is `[660004, 57000]`, perhaps you should add a space into the `join`

Answer (score 2):

Currently I had the same problem, did it with the toString() method

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,[1,2,3]]
var array2 = [1,2,3,[1,2,3]]

array1 == array2 // false
array1.toString() == array2.toString() // true

var array3 = [1,2,3,[1,3,2]]

// Take attention
array1.toString() == array3.toString() // false
```

Comment: great fresh solution, I've resolved that problem 3 years ago by accepted answer, but your solution seems to be very nice for me, thanks. :)

Comment: hehe, sure, maybe some else will find it nice too ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could also doing it with the [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org)-framework for functional programming.

```
function containsElements(elements) {
  _.find(boreholes, function(ele){ return _.isEqual(ele, elements); });
}

if(containsElements([66000, 457000])) {
  console.log('ok');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't quite clear if there can be more than 2 elements in an array, so this might work

```
var boreholes = [[66000, 457000],[1111,2222]]; 
var it = [66000, 457000];

function hasIt(boreholes, check) {
  var len = boreholes.length;
  for (var a = 0; a < len; a++) {
    if (boreholes[a][0] == check[0] && boreholes[a][1] == check[1]) {
       // ok
       return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

if (hasIt(boreholes, it)) {
  // ok, it has it
}
```

Comment: can there be 3 or more elements in the element that needs to be checked against bareholes?

Comment: ohh sorry.. all elements are xy cooridantes, so there can not be more than 2 elements in one element.

Comment: oh ok, then you can easily use this implementation